# How to make visual studio code to not correct my code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I’m learning Angular 6 and I use Visual Studio Code. And I meet a problem when writing code. I try to write this :

```
<input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name">
```

And VSCode change it to this :

```
<input [(ngmodel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name">
```

That’s a problem beacuse width the change, the code don’t work anymore. I have to edit that specific page with an other editor to get it to stay as it has to.

I have not met this problem with other bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Go the File -> Preferences in the top left of the Visual Studio menu. It should pop up an extremely long file containing roughly 500 or so settings you can edit. It sounds like your issue could be fixed by turning the line

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on",
```

to

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
```

Place the change in the right-hand screen on your screen to override the defaults. If this doesn't work, go through some of the other choices in the "Editor" file on the left side of the screen.

Comment: Thank you for  your answer. But it dont't work. I have seen with other editor.* too. Maybe I have to fin a good extention for Angular.